# Create a series that answers the following criteria

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've had a question I don't really know how to approach.
Basically I need to construct a series that statisfies the following criteria:

- Is a Leibniz series of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} a_{n}$
- $a_{n} > 0$ , is a monotonically decreasing series that converges to $0$
- The leibniz series is also a geometric series, and $a_{n} = a_{0} q^n$
- The leibniz series converges to 4

I don't really know how to go about constructing a series like this - any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, really, any convergent geometric series you write down will work.

Comment: whoops! forgot to say the series needs to converge to 4 - sorry haha

Comment: Again, take your favorite convergent geometric series.  Work out it's sum, and multiply by whatever you need to get to $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} a_{n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} a_0 q^n\\
&=-a_0 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-q)^n\\
&=-a_0  \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-q)^n - 1\right)\\
&= -a_0 \left(\frac{1}{1+q} - 1\right) = \frac{a_0 q}{1+q}
\end{aligned}$$

Now, you need to have $\frac{a_0 q}{1+q}=4$ and $0 \lt q \lt 1$ as $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing.

$a_0 = 12$ and $q = \frac{1}{2}$ will do the job.

Comment: can you explain to me how you did the transition from the second to the third row?

Comment: For $n = 0$, $(-1)^n = 1$. So I added $1$ and subtracted it.